# Output Database size in json format (Mariadb from Centos7)

Tags: mysql, json, linux, bash, shell

Anyone knows how can I output this data in a json format
[Full output using mysql command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VImC2.png) . I don't know how can I get them one by one. Using Bash Script. Thanking you ahead of time :)

Basically, The script needs to compute the size of the databaase per GB per client/dbname. Then sent it as json format.

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
{
    "client_code": "information_schema",
    "key": "disk_usage",
    "value": "0.000069"
  },
  {
    "client_code": "mysql",
    "key": "disk_usage",
    "value": "0.000611"
  },
  {
    "client_code": "newdb",
    "key": "disk_usage",
    "value": "1GB"
  }
]
```

Comment: They say that it can be solved through static loop. But still I'm in blank. Any ideas will be appreciated . Thnksssss

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass the `--json` to mysql command line query to get the output in JSON format. More on this [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-shell-json-output.html)

`select table_schema, sum((data_length+index_length)/1024/1024) AS MB from information_schema.tables group by 1; | mysqlsh --json=pretty --sqlc --uri root@192.168.1.141:3306`

**EDIT :**

Although direct JSON outputting without 3rd party apps is not possible yet in MySQL or MariaDB. That said, found an interesting post to convert the normal atomic table to BLOB table and parse it with column_json() function. You can find it [here](https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/creating-json-documents-with-mariadb/), If you are using CONNECT to data forge then you might find [this](http://serge.frezefond.com/2015/04/select-from-a-mariadb-table-into-json-format/) article useful.

Comment: I forgot to tell, I'm using mariadb in centos 7. and tried that syntax. Also check if there's the same syntax for mariadb didn't find any.  Anyways thanks for your answer

Comment: Can you update the question with where it says you are using MariaDB and while you are at it, format the output to code format for ease of readabiltiy

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution, What I did was I inner join two database so that I can get the value and for the json output I use a tool csvtojson.